# Method decorator to register callbacks

Tags: python

I'm working on a callback system in Python. The to-be callbacks are methods of a class. I register these with a decorator.
Here is some pseudo class representing this:

```
class MyClass(ABC):
  def __init__(self):
    self.cb_stack = {}

  def register_callback(self, callback, name):
    self.cb_stack[name] = callback     

  @register_callback('mycb')
  def myCallback(self, input):
    self.do_things()
```

I suspect each decorator is executed by default.

I would like however for the decorator to be executed when `obj.myCallback()` is called, and to prevent `myCallback()` from executing at that moment (which should be the case here).

The alternative I have is to write it in the long form for each callback, which should work like so:

```
class MyClassLong(ABC):
  def __init__(self):
    self.cb_stack = {}

  def register_callback(self, callback, name):
    self.cb_stack[name] = callback     

  def myCallback(self):
    def func(self, input): 
      self.do_things()
    self.register_callback(func, 'mycb')
```

Notice it adds two lines of codes, so it's not really an issue but more how to make something clean.
Does anyone knows how if it is achievable, and how ?

Comment: You are fundamentally misunderstanding decorators. For starters, your decorator *doesn't return anything* so `self.myCallback` will be `None`, and it isn't handling additional arguments correctly, and would throw a `TypeError`.

Comment: Also, `self.cb_stack = {}` would throw a `NameError`

Comment: I added a correct `init` which I first omited for simplicity. Indeed my callback should return nothing: it is to be added to the dict `self.cb_stack` ! :)

Comment: No, you don't understand **you essentially deleted your callback**. There *is no more function anymore* after you run `@register_callback('mycb')`, well, actually, **that errors because the arguments aren't handled correctly**. It's all entirely wrong, and like I said, you don't seem to understand decorators. Decorators *need to return the callable*

Comment: Ok thanks for the info. Could you provide an exemple on how to handle the arguments correctly so that I understand this bit ? I'll go for the second ("long") option then :)

Answer (score 1):

So both of your versions have an argument `input` that is ignored but to a different function both times, so I don't know what you want exactly, but if we take that out, you could simpy use:

```
class MyClass(ABC):
  def __init__(self):
    self.cb_stack = {}

  def register_callback(self, callback, name):
    self.cb_stack[name] = callback     

  def myCallback(self):
    self.register_callback(self.do_things, 'mycb')
```

Comment: There is an extra function that executes the callback stack that looks like: `def exec(self, input): for cb in self.cb_stack: cb(input)` (all callbacks work on the same input, like a pipeline). Your suggestion matches the "long" version, it is indeed simpler that way :)

Answer (score 1):

class and method definitions are processed only once when the class is declared so you can only use decorators at the class level (not at the instance level).  If your list of callbacks applied to all instances of the class, you could define a parameterized decorator to register them:

```
# defines a callback list as a dictionary
# provides the decorator

class Callbacks(dict):        
    def register(self,name):
        def decorate(f):
            self[name] = f         
            return f
        return decorate

class MyClass:

    cb_stack = Callbacks() 

    @cb_stack.register('mycb')
    def myCallback(self, param):
        print("myCallback called",param)

    def triggerCallbacks(self):
        for n,f in type(self).cb_stack.items(): f(self,n)

mc = MyClass()

mc.triggerCallbacks() 

myCallback called mycb
```

You can also use this for subclasses:

```
class MySubclass(MyClass):
    
    cb_stack = Callbacks(MyClass.cb_stack)
    
    @cb_stack.register('mycb2')
    def myCallback2(self, param):
        print("myCallback2 called",param)

msc = MySubclass()

msc.triggerCallbacks() 

myCallback called mycb
myCallback2 called mycb2
```